# HTML <select> tag. Selected option does not display unless page is refreshed

Tags: php, html, mysql, selected

So I have a very odd error.  I have a value, $ll1_name, that is derived from a MySQL query, through PHP.

Here is the example code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT data_txt FROM field_data WHERE itemid = $uid AND fieldid = 16");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$ll1_key = $row[0];
//$ll1 = $row[0];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT info FROM landlords WHERE key = '$ll1_key'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$ll1_name = $row[0];
```

^ that sets the variables to the correct landlords, if they exist for a certain tenant.

```
<select name=ll1>


<?php
if (is_null($ll1_key)){
?>
    <option selected> Empty </option>
<?php
}

else{
?>

    <option selected value="<?php echo "$ll1_key"; ?>"> <?php echo "$ll1_name"; ?> </option>
<?php   
}

while ($curLandlord = mysql_fetch_array($landlordRows)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo "$curLandlord[0]"; ?>"> <?php echo "$curLandlord[1]"; ?></option>

<?php
}
?>


</select>
```

^That populates the drop down.  If it is null, it defaults to "Empty".  Otherwise, it will make the selected option the current land lord.

However, the field is blank.  The page source looks like this:

```
<option selected value="ll1_72">  </option>
```

You can see the correct key for the landlord is set as the value; but my php code outputs nothing for the selected text in the field.  HOWEVER, if you refresh the page, it loads properly with the land lord's name.  But the source code looks exactly the same.  If I refresh firefox without cached data (ctrl+shift+r), then I still get a blank field after refreshing.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?  I see this behavior across multiple browsers (IE 11, Chrome, and Firefox).

Comment: What is `$landlordRows`? If that equals `$row` then you are only selecting one column so `[1]` is empty.

Comment: you sure this isn't throwing you an error? `WHERE key` <<< Then again, you're not checking for errors for it.

Comment: Try setting no-cache header?

Comment: Check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) out.

Comment: I thought it was a MySQL error at first; but if the correct value is returned after refreshing the page, it couldn't be.  There are underscores in the landlord key though (not my doing), and I thought that was the issue at first.

Comment: $landlordRows are the rest of the options, which are generated fine.  It's a query that selects all landlords and their values from the table.  I just loop through that; but I want the tenants current landlord to be automatically selected from the drop down if the tenant is already assigned to one of the landlords.

Comment: I edited my question and deleted my comment.  They weren't unconstructive--that was poor wording.  I just felt the first two were poorly thought out replies, and I saw they flagged the question.  I've been struggling with this issue for days, I am just growing frustrated.  I am not trying to have a bad attitude.

Comment: The second comment is by no means "un-constructive". For that matter neither is the first. The first is a perfectly reasonable comment trying to make sense of your data/code and the second comment is probably (no scratch that), it ***is*** the best comment here.

Comment: `var_dump($row);` after your second fetch and see what's there

Comment: Also, ll1_key is a variable name.  The word key does not appear in any of the results fetched from the database.  ll1_72 would translate to john doe, after the query.  This database was created with an outdated Joomla! extension, and many of these weird abstractions were made because its an extension, so I have to live with some of the weird practices they implemented, and make it work.

Comment: @theCowardlyFrench did you even look at the duplicate question/answer?

Comment: @PatrickQ var_dump($row) gives me ll1_72 for the key, and NULL for the landlord name.  However, the same behavior still happens after refreshing the page.  The dump of the variable is still NULL; but the correct landlord appears.

Comment: @Script47 Yes.  Like I said, the variable name is "l11_key".  I am operating under the assumption the string "key" can be compounded with something else and not be reserved; unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Right, now look at the link I provided in the comment I posted *19* minutes  ago, do *CTRL + F* then type *key* and follow the trails of highlighted text and tell me what you see.

Comment: @Script47 I am blind and now I see.  I hadn't even looked past my variable names and into the rest of the query I had been staring at it so long.  Just a moment, let me try to escape the reserved word my in query.....

Comment: Hey, it worked!  Thanks so much @Script47 and everyone else (I can only link one person).  I'm just a stubborn idiot.  I'd apologize but it's probably a useless platitude.  Thanks for persisting and answering my questions, I truly appreciate it, because I know that I wouldn't have been as patient with someone as unwilling of help as myself.

Comment: You should thank @Fred-ii-, after all, it was his "un-constructive" comment which turned out to be the most constructive comment. Just listen to people, if you don't understand what they mean, ask them to clarify. Don't drive people away by saying negative things.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Appreciate the _constructive_ comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try without quotes:

```
<?php echo $ll1_name; ?>
```

Comment: That is not the issue, also double quotes allow you to `echo` or `print` variables in them.

Comment: I've already tried that, unfortunately.

Comment: Unless you are a bot you will notice the original poster responding to my post AND getting an answer elsewhere. There is no need for your 'review'